# Volume of the solid enclosed by curves.

Tags: integration

Find the volume of the solid enclosed by : $z=7−x^2, z=−2, y=−1, y=4$. My answer is 180, the answer in my book is totally different.

This is my multiple integral:

$\int_{-1}^{4} ( \int_{-3}^{3}\left| 7-x^2-(-2)\right|dx )dy$

Comment: $x2$ or $x^2$ ?

Comment: $x^2$ i'm sorry

Comment: My answer is 180 too.

Answer (score 0):

First, find the area enclosed by a parabolic cross section in the $xz$-plane enclosed by the curves $$z = f(x) = 7-x^2, \quad z = g(x) = -2:$$  this is simply $$B = \int_{x=-3}^3 f(x) - g(x) \, dx = \int_{x=-3}^3 9-x^2 \, dx = 36.$$  Thus the total volume is simply the area of the base $B$ times the height of the parabolic cylinder, which is the distance between $y = -1$ and $y = 4$, which is $h = 5$.  Thus the total volume is $V = Bh = 5(36) =180$, as you found.